# How can one use Vue.js code from Codepen?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, copy-paste, codepen

I want to use [this](https://codepen.io/dawgrex/details/mdyQgOw) code from Codepen. So, I right clicked on the `result` frame and chose `View Frame source`. Then I copied the source code and pasted it in my own text-editor.

But my webpage shows the codepart as blank.

[image]

I copied the source starting from `<style>` till `</body>` and inserted in my component.
When using the ZIP instead, I don't know how to use the code, because I just have a component and the ZIP contains a script.js and a style.css

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe first look at the vuejs guides for [installation and setup](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html).

Comment: @palaѕн I've already set up Vue and created different components, but I think my approach to "copy-pasting" in Vue is wrong

Comment: If you only want to have 1 page start a new HTML-Frame and insert html-part into it, then you copy and paste css part into ```<style>``` and the javascript part into ```<script>```. Then you only need to change vue's [CDN](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CDN) in the html tag

Comment: @J.Dario Thanks Dario, but what do you mean with change vue's CDN in the html tag? I tried `import {src} from "vinyl-fs";

    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"`

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5MMgEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's copy-and-pasting for dummies:
This is the html part:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dayparting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <table class="dayparts table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td class="cell-label presets-label"></td>
                    <td colspan="24"><span class="cell-label presetsSubtitle-label"></span>
                        <select v-model="selected" @change='clearAll();selectedFunc()'>
                            <option value="">Select a Preset</option>
                            <option value="0">None</option>
                            <option value="1">Afternoons</option>
                            <option value="2">Evenings</option>
                            <option value="3">Mornings</option>
                            <option value="4">Weekdays</option>
                            <option value="5">Weekends</option>
                            <option value="6">Weekends including Friday</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2"></td>
                    <td class="cell-label am-label" colspan="12">AM</td>
                    <td class="cell-label pm-label" colspan="12">PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hour-row">
                    <td class="hour" v-for="hour in times" v-bind:value="hour.hour" v-on:click='setTime'>{{hour.hour}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody @mousedown='mouseDown' @mouseup='mouseUp' @mousemove='mouseMove'>
                <tr class="day" v-for="day in days">
                    <td class="cell-label day-label" v-bind:value="day.dayNumber" v-bind:day-value="day.dayNumber"
                        v-on:click='activateDay'>{{day.dayName}}</td>
                    <td class='dayparts-cell' v-bind:value="hour.hour" data='day'
                        v-bind:class="{active: hour.isActive, preactive: hour.isPreActive}" v-for='hour in day.times'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the "head":

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dayparting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
</head>
```

1) Remove `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` and add `<style></style>` in the same place. Fill it with the content of the css-part.

2) Replace "vue.js" in `<script src="vue.js"></script>` with "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js" when you're in development or with "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11" for production.

Then go to the bottom of your html-code and find `<script src="main.js"></script>`. Remove it and add an empty `<script></script>` instead. Fill it with the copied Javascript part.

Now your page should run properly.

Tip: Do not use `Ctrl + A` in Codepen to select everything since it selects a few extra words then.

Comment: What was your mistake?